# SQLAlchemy joined table inheritance with discriminator being part of the primary key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Lets start with an example [from the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html) for Joined Table Inheritance

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(20))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on':type,
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee'
    }

class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'engineer'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    engineer_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'engineer',
    }

class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'manager'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.id'), primary_key=True)
    manager_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'manager',
    }
```

Now I needed something like:

```
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(20), primary_key=True) // <----------- Change

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on':type,
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee'
    }

class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'engineer'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) // <----------- Change
    type = Column(String(20), primary_key=True) // <----------- Added
    engineer_name = Column(String(30))

    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([id , type ],             // <----------- Added
                                      [Employee.id, Employee.type],
                                      ondelete='CASCADE', ),)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'engineer',
    }

class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'manager'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) // <----------- Change
    type = Column(String(20), primary_key=True) // <----------- Added
    manager_name = Column(String(30))


    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([id , type ],             // <----------- Added
                                      [Employee.id, Employee.type],
                                      ondelete='CASCADE', ),)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'manager',
    }
```

**My question**

While the above code works, I'm not that proficient in SQLAlchemy and interested to know if there are problems with that code that I'm not aware of yet and might encounter, and more importantly, is there a correct/better way to implement this joined table inheritance with multiple primary keys as shown above.

**Note**: The main challenge is that in the docs example, the discriminator, `type`, is only placed within the base class, but I needed the type to be a primary key as well.